# Requiring normal javascript file from node compiled script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Firstly, i want to state i'm very new to anything to do with node...
Before i state my issue, here is some example code to refer to.

test.js

```
//test.js
const myMessage = 'Bananas';
export default myMessage; // Im not to sure about this line (problem)
```

main.js

```
//main.js
const test = require('./test.js');
console.log(test.myMessage);
```

I want to require a normal external javascript script called `test.js` from a node compiled script called `main.js`. I have compiled `main.js` simply by typing `node main.js` in my terminal. But node spat out an error 'Unexpected token export'. I know I'm doing something wrong here. Do i use "Modules"? How do i exclude the export statement?

Thanks for reading, sorry if my problem is making people facepalm on how dumb this issue might seem.

Comment: What do you mean by "*a node compiled script*"?

Comment: In any case, it should be `export const myMessage = '…';`, not a default export, if you want to access it by `.myMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export` syntax is not yet supported in Nodejs (its in an alpha version), instead Nodejs provides a global object* (`module.exports`) which is what you get back with the `require()` call, so you just have to set that objects property to the thing you want to export:

```
 const myMessage = 'Bananas';
 module.exports.myMessage = myMessage;
```

or shorter:

```
 exports.myMessage = 'Bananas';
```

---

*global in the sense of "it exists although you haven't defined it", actually for every script that gets executed, a new  `module` object will be created that can only be accessed inside of that script.

Comment: `module.exports.myMessage = 'Bananas';`?

Answer (score 4):

I think the external file you are trying to require is **esModule**. Such files can't be directly required unless you transpile them to **commonJSModule**. You have two solutions.

- Transpile esModule to commonJSModule using babel. (or change export to module.exports in your test.js)
- If you use new node    version you can change it's extension to .mjs (rename test.js to test.mjs)

Please take a look at this Medium article which should help.

https://medium.com/@giltayar/native-es-modules-in-nodejs-status-and-future-directions-part-i-ee5ea3001f71

Answer (score 1):

Use babel register: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/register @babel/preset-env --save
```

And require it in your main.js:

```
require('@babel/register')({
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  ignore: [
    /node_modules/
  ]
});
```

This will parse other required files through babel which are not in node_modules, so ES6 import/export will work, and it will also polyfill features not present in your current version of node (node: true).

Note this should only be used if you have to require front-end scripts you can't reasonably modify. It's heavyweight to parse every require so if you do have to, make `ignore` as strict as possible (or even better use the `only` option) so you're only parsing what you need.